# xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object show after I inset two subfigure

Tags: subfloats, texstudio, xdvipdfmx

I met an unexpected mistake when I used Latex Studio. I just want to insert two subfigure in my words using the command:

```
begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[synchionization time]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{figures/056.pdf}
        \label{fig5}
    }
    
    \subfigure[duty cycle]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{figures/057.pdf}
        \label{fig6}
    }
    \caption{result}
    \label{fig:44}
\end{figure}
```

And the terminal show:
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex
xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object. No output PDF file written.
fwrite: Invalid argument
xelatex.exe:
Process exited with error(s)
Can anyone met this error or have a good idea to fix it?

Comment: the error is known and normally means the pdf you are trying to include is broken. Sometimes one can repair them by resaving them with adobe or ghostscript or pdftk.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error output:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)) [1] [2]
Chapter 1.
[3] [4]
Chapter 2.
[5] [6]
Chapter 3.
[7] [8] [9] [10]
Chapter 4.
[11]
Overfull \hbox (4.64401pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--189
[]\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 This makes the use of \TU/Inter(0)/m/it/10 CTRL \TU/Inter
(0)/m/n/10 key combinations more ergonomic. 
[12] [13]
Overfull \hbox (2.98775pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 205--212
\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 reachable through the OLED menu. Each cell icon corresponds
 
[14] [15] [16]
Chapter 5.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
Overfull \hbox (15.37852pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 251--258
\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 for your computer to execute, but also to write programs (s
cripts) 
[17]
xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object.

No output PDF file written.
```

The page in question in my latex also used pdf figures.

The problem went away after installing the ghostscript package (I am running Debian).